# Embedding OpenJDK in Application

Tags: java

I know it's possible to bundle the regular Oracle JRE in a Java application if you want to distribute it as a stand-alone application without requiring users to have the JRE already installed, but is it possible to do the same thing with OpenJDK?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the OpenJDK license

Comment: Actually I'm not asking about the license at all.  I'm asking about the technical feasibility and possibility of doing exactly what I asked.

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you are looking for? https://medium.com/@adam_carroll/java-packager-with-jdk11-31b3d620f4a8

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but an answer seems appropriate today (since this is new-ish)

The Java Platform Module System (Java 9+) supports this idea directly with the jlink tool. It's actually one of the specific, stated, goals of the system. And, to make it even better, a properly modularized software product will include only the necessary parts of the JRE and libraries, thereby remaining relatively small.